# Behavior of sleep with and without new line character

Tags: c++, sleep

Consider the below code, in which there are two test area

In 1st test (Test 1 :: without new line) the programmed sleeped for 10 seconds (5*2) as given. But all the 5 *'s printed `only after the 10 seconds finished.`

In 2nd test (Test 2 :: with new line) the programmed sleeped for 10 seconds (5*2) as given. But #'s is printed after every two second sleep.

What is the logic behind this?

```
Compiler:g++
platform:UNIX
```

Also,

i studied sleep is not a part of standard library? we need to use pthread.h

How then sleep here worked for me without including pthread.h

```
 #include<iostream>

 int main()
 {
    using namespace std;

 // Test 1 :: without new line
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    sleep(2);
    cout<<"*";
 }

 cout<<"\n";

 // Test 2 :: with new line
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    sleep(2);
    cout<<"#\n";
 }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `std::cout` doesn't flush immediately (but might if it sees a `'\n'` character) ...

Comment: `sleep` is in `unistd.h` IIRC, which could very well be included by your implementation's `<iostream>`.

Comment: `sleep()` is not a part of pthreads. It predates POSIX threads by a long time. It is a part of the UNIX library (so obviously later adopted by POSIX, but not as the POSIX threads library). Vinoth, you are happening to get `sleep()` "for free". Nothing is free. Those freebies have a big cost. You should have done `man sleep` at the command line (or possibly `man 3 sleep`) to see what headers you need to include. It's going to say `unistd.h`, not `iostream`.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes sleep is defined under the unistd.h I accept yourself. But how it works without that one, sorry am really confused....

Comment: @Vinoth - `<iostream>` on a Unix machine happens to `#include <unistd.h>`. You have access to all functions defined in that header, for free! You don't need to include `unistd.h` if you have already include `iostream`. Except you do. You should never depend on such freebies.

Answer (score 4):

When connected to a terminal `std::cout` is line buffered. You need an explicit `cout << flush;` to make each `*` appear individually.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your first question, cout does not flush immediately.  The time it does is dependent on a number of factors, but in this case it appears it's only flushing when it sees a newline character.  If you want to force a flush, you can use

```
cout << flush;
// or
cout.flush();
```

About pthreads: it is probable your compiler is just including the required header by default.

Comment: How it can be included by default? Is there is any way to do it... Is it possible like that

Comment: Is there a way to do what?

Comment: am sorry... how it possible

Comment: The compiler includes a number of headers by default. Most compilers used to include more, but fewer have been included over time to speed up average compilation time (every header included increases compilation time).  As an example of another header that's always included by default is the definition of all of the basic types.  At some point, your compiler may no longer be including pthread.h, but when it doesn't any longer it will be pretty obvious. Generally you should try to make sure to include all the headers you'll need, so I would personally include it anyway